# Scraping an dom element with mouse movement

Tags: ruby, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape http://ventusky.com/. When mouse is moved around, it shows some data near that mouse pointer. I am using `selenium`. When I look at the browser console I can see that `mousemove` event listener is adding this data. My code.

```
test = driver.find_element(:id,"h")
driver.action.move_to(test, 100, 100).perform
elem=wait.until{driver.find_element(:class,"yy")}
puts elem.attribute "outerHTML"
```

But i do not get any data from the element `elem`. Its `text` is empty. I do not see anything happening on browser also when the script is run. Can someone help me to figure out this problem. I am pretty new to scrapping.

I am using `ruby` even though it doesnt matter. I can find the ruby equivalent .

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a sleep before the move command. This page takes time to load, so either, you add a `finished_loading_elem=wait.until{driver.find_element(:id,"z")}` or add an implicit wait, like `Thread.Sleep` in other languages.

Also, I suggest move to offset like 250, 250 because 100,100 could fall on the search bar.

Comment: I tried changing coords and added waiting but its the same. But ``mousemove`` event listener is not being called.

Comment: Are you sure the mouse move action happened after the page finished loading?

Comment: I understood the problem here. If you check out the website and click on any point , it will add a new ``div`` with location of the point. when i click once more. it dissapears. next click for some reason is not adding the ``div``. It gets timed out as it cant find the element.